# How to shift signal phase in matlab from this circuit?

Tags: signal, signal-processing, matlab, phase-shift

[image]

The circuit shown is in matlab. Sinus signal is provided by vpin by connecting from PCI. The sinus signal is looks like on the scope. The problem is i want to shift signal phase, from the picture below is circuit needed to shift the sinus signal phase, but there's a red dot that i can't connect the shift circuit (R-C) with my sinus to shift signal phase... How to solve this? Is there any way to shift the signal phase?

[image]

Comment: Is there an EE question lurking here or is it just about how to use MATLAB?

Comment: Add a transfer function block for the RC network. Or, a pure time delay block with delay, \$\small T\$, will give a phase lag of \$\small \omega T\$ rad without affecting the gain.

Answer (score 1):

The reason there are "red dot's" is because you are attempting to cross domains.

**Simulink** contains multiple physical domains which prior to **Simscape** was not that obvious (in **simscape** electrial, mechanical, magnetic, hydraulic, etc.. all have unique trace colours).

In the example shot above you are attempting to connect BASE Simulink to **SimPowerSystems** (Specialist Technology, not Simscape electrical). These are completely incompatible and you would need to use  "Controlled Voltage Source" to produce a time varying **SimPowerSystem** voltage that could be fed into a passive array to create a phase shift and an attenuation.

If you are just after a phaseshift may I recommend using a Transport Delay block (Simulink -> Continuous)

If however you are after a more electrical affect then a suitable transfer function \$\frac{1}{1+\tau s}\$ would produce an equivalent electrical response while residing within the S-domain/Simulink

Or convert the model to SimScape/SimPowerSystem and model based upon "real" R's and C's

[image]

[image]