# Simulate physical FM Transmitter circuit on Matlab Simulink

Tags: circuit-design, matlab, simulink

I am new to matlab. I was working on a simple modulator that I have to simulate. I've faced a problem with connecting the output frequency from the resonance circuit to the scope, A red dotted line appears. After further googling and searching in mathworks, I've found a converter to connect them.

Now my problem is in the input signal. I am applying a signal generator to the input which is the join that collects a capacitor and resistor to the transistor base, the below images shows the whole circuit :

[image: Circuit]

Now I found this converting tool :
https://www.mathworks.com/help/physmod/simscape/ref/simulinkpsconverter.html

But it still cannot be connected to the joint that I want. check this:

[image: Circuit]

Anyone can suggest what's wrong with this type of connections and how to fix this? Noting that I am using matlab 2018.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is physical domains.

The black traces are the traditional simulink s-domain traces

The brown signals are physical but domain agnostic trace

The Blue signals are the electrical domain traces.

You have found the Simulink to Physical port converter to map a simulink signal into the Simscape domain, now you need a source for this signal to control. A voltage source should be all you need

[image]

[How to shift signal phase in matlab from this circuit?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/248064/how-to-shift-signal-phase-in-matlab-from-this-circuit/248074#248074)

[Trying to simulate a simple micro inverter, Cant connect scope](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/321336/trying-to-simulate-a-simple-micro-inverter-cant-connect-scope/321340#321340)

Comment: Thank you very much :) .. You've solved my problem.